# Different Fragment view for tablet

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created an app using the Android Wizard and using a `ViewPager` to contain all three of my fragments. The main activity is contained in a "activity_main.xml" and contains a `ViewPager` which inturn contains a `PagerTitleStrip`. My MainActivity extends the `FragmentActivity` from support library.

I have checked the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on Android Developers. I created a folder called "layout-sw600dp" and added another "activity_main.xml" in there. I added my Fragments in there inside a `LinearLayout`. When I run this on a 7" tablet, my app force closes with a NPE at this line, `mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);`.

I understand that I get this NPE here because it is invoking my xml from sw600dp folder, but how do I specify multiple fragments in a single view for tablets?

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

**Edit - Added some source code, tried to keep only relevant data to keep the post short**

As you can find below, most of the code is generated by the wizard/adt-plugin.

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

layout-sw600dp/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_one"...
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_two"...
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
    // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
    // Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(...
```

Comment: Post some code to better understand the issue. From what you have told us, you are not using a pager on the tablet layout so you should add some checks to not use that in code, and instead show the fragments on the linearLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like on the tablet you don't want a ViewPager, you just want to display all the fragments, so you don't have a ViewPager in that layout. So when you try to set mViewPager it's setting as null because there is no ViewPager in that layout. so, your options, if I have seen the situation correctly, are to add a dummy ViewPager to the tablet layout (Don't recommend), or to add an if statement. Remember that mViewPager will be set to null anytime the user is on a tablet, so any code you have involving will throw an error if it's not inside an if statement like the one below.

```
if(mViewPager!=null){
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter)
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, without adding a dummy ViewPager. I just checked if mViewPager is null and added all ViewPager related code if it is not null and my app is running on Nexus 7